# Were there two elves named Glorfindel?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

In the Silmarillion, an elf named Glorfindel is killed in a duel with a Balrog at the battle for Gondolin.  (He kills the Balrog as well.)  Then in The Fellowship of the Ring, an elf named Glorfindel meets Frodo, Sam, Merry, Pippin and Aragorn and helps them get a wounded Frodo to Rivendell.

This would be the only time that Tolkien uses the same name for two different elves.  Is there any connection between these two elves?

Comment: I think Glorfindel got reincarnated as Liv Tyler :P

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Glorfindel is confirmed as the same Elf in two separate passages in the History of Middle-earth (HoME).

First of all from The Return of the Shadow (Vol VI of HoME), written by Christopher Tolkien:

> Also very notable is 'Glorfindel tells of his ancestry in Gondolin.'
> Years later, long after the publication ofThe Lord of the Rings, my
> father  gave a great deal of thought to the matter of Glorfindel, and
> at that time  he wrote: '[The use of Glorfindel] in The Lord of the
> Rings is one of the  cases of the somewhat random use of the names
> found in the older  legends, now referred to as The Silmarillion,
> which escaped reconsideration in the final published form of The
> Lord of the Rings.' He came to the  conclusion that Glorfindel of
> Gondolin, who fell to his death in combat  with a Balrog after the
> sack of the city (II.192 - 4, IV.145), and  Glorfindel of Rivendell
> were one and the same: he was released from  Mandos and returned to
> Middle-earth in the Second Age.

Secondly, an essay from the People of Middle-earth (Vol XII of HoME) in Tolkien's own words detail how Glorfindel would be able return from death:

> When  Glorfindel  was  slain  his  spirit  would  then  go   to
> Mandos   and  be  judged,  and  then  would  remain  in  the   Halls
> of   Waiting  until  Manwe  granted  him  release.  The  Elves  were destined  to   be  by  nature  'immortal',  within  the  unknown
> limits  of  the life  of the  Earth   as   a  habitable   realm,  and
> their  disembodiment   was  a  grievous thing. It was  the duty,
> therefore, of  the Valar  to restore  them,  if they  were slain,  to
> incarnate  life, if  they desired  it -  unless  for  some  grave
> (and  rare)  reason: such  as deeds  of great  evil,  or  any  works
> of  malice  of  which  they  remained obdurately  unrepentant.
>
> When
> they   were  re-embodied   they  could   remain  in  Valinor,  or
> return  to  Middle-earth  if their  home had  been there.  We  can
> therefore  reasonably  suppose  that  Glorfindel,   after  the
> purging or  forgiveness of  his part  in the  rebellion of  the
> Noldor,  was   released   from   Mandos   and   became   himself again,   but  remained  in   the  Blessed   Realm  -   for  Gondolin was  destroyed  and  all  or  most  of  his kin  had perished.

Tolkien has a couple of theories as to when Glorfindel returned:

> We could  then reasonably  suppose that Glorfindel (possibly as one of a small party, more probably as a  sole  companion) landed  with Gandalf  - Olorin  about Third Age  1000.

Alternatively:

> We may then best suppose that Glorfindel returned  during the Second Age, before the 'shadow' fell on  Numenor, and  while the Numenoreans  were  welcomed  by  the  Eldar as  powerful allies.

Answer (score 36):

It depends a bit on your point of view.  Glorfindel died and was eventually reincarnated, essentially the same as Gandalf was (though, being a maia, Gandalf's revival required the intervention of Eru, whereas the Valar did it themselves for Glorfindel). So it is the same Glorfindel in spirit, but not in body, however you wish to interpret that.

According to the [LotR wiki](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Glorfindel), In the First Age:

> [Glorfindel] slew a balrog, though he died in the process. Like all elves, he was re-embodied in the Halls of Awaiting.

Then in the Third Age,

> In recognition of his skill, he was sent by the Valar back to Middle-earth either as a precursor to or companion of the Istari to aid the fight against Sauron.

And later in the article:

> He was said to have been resurrected by the Valar and be given the same degree of power as a Maiar.

And finally (and perhaps most directly related to the question at hand):

> There has been some confusion about the Glorfindel of Gondolin and the Glorfindel of Rivendell. They may or may not have been meant to be the same person (though an early draft of The Fellowship of the Ring contained a note that "Glorfindel tells of his ancestry in Gondolin"). However, as Tolkien felt that elf names were unique (though he doubled others), he decided to find a way to correct his perceived mistake. He did this by making them the same but reincarnated person. Tolkien stated that Glorfindel's spirit returned to the Halls of Awaiting, but was after a time re-embodied by the Valar. He then returned to Middle-earth (either in the mid-Second Age, or as a companion of the Blue Wizards in the Third).
>
> He is also said to be an Elven Prince, which has led to speculation that Glorfindel is the son of Finarfin or one of his descendants.

So it appears it was originally a mistake, but JRRT managed to find a way to correct it.

Comment: http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/g/glorfindel.php mentions that the primary source for Glorfindel being the same Elf is in the History of Middle-Earth, Vol XII (The Peoples of Middle-Earth).  Just to confirm it's not just wiki-speculation (there needs to be a proper word for that). :)

Comment: @dlanod "Canon".

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear, and I can direct you to further discussion [here](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/g/glorfindel.php). I personally prefer the reading that Glorfindel is in fact a re-embodiment of the Glorfindel of Gondolin, giving us a glimpse of the relationship between the Elves of ME and the fantastic powers beyond the sea.  It's clear in several examples that it is within the power of the Valar to grant re-embodiment where it is desired and especially deserved, as with Gandalf and with Beren and Luthien.

Besides that, Elves are long-lived (immortal) - I'm pretty sure there's no other example of Elves sharing the same names (though Men have been named after both Men and Elves).